# Showing region between $x$ axis and graph is in ${\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R^2})$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathbb{R^2},{\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R^2}),\lambda^2)$ be a measure space where $\lambda^2$ is the two dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Let $u:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty]$ be a Borel measurable function. How do I show that $S[u]:=\{(x,y):0\le y \le u(x)\}$ is in ${\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R^2})$?

I was given the hint to approximate $u$ by an increasing sequence of simple functions $(f_j)$ that converges pointwise to $u$. Then $S[u]=\bigcup_j S[f_j]$ and since $S[f_j]\in {\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R^2})$ we conclude that $S[u]$ is also in ${\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R^2})$.

However, how do we see that $S[u]=\bigcup_j S[f_j]$ actually holds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As pointed out by satokun in the comments, my answer is only correct if $S[u]$ would have been defined as $S[u] = \{(x,y) : 0 \leq y < u(x)\}$ instead of $S[u] = \{(x,y) : 0 \leq y \leq u(x)\}$. This means that either the hint is misleading or that there is a misprint in the exercise. There is also a nice blog post about this problem, found [here](https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/upper-and-lower-ordinate-sets/) (this post was also found by satokun). According to this post, we have the following possibilites:

- The hint in the problem is correct. This means that there is probably a misprint in the definition of $S[u]$ (as mentioned above). If this is the case, then my answer remains correct.
- The definition of $S[u]$ is correct. In this case the blog post shows that the hint is probably wrong. Furthermore, we don't know if $S[u]$ is considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\bar{\mathbb{R}} \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}$. Since the underlying set of the measure space is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and we have to show that $S[u] \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, we can assume that it is meant a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and in this case the correct answer is provided by the second-last paragraph of the blog post. However, if $S[u]$ is meant as a subset of $\bar{\mathbb{R}} \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}$, then in general $S[u] \notin \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ without any further assumptions on $u$.
- The defintion of $u$ is not correct and should have been $u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ instead of $u: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$. Then $S[u] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, and if the definiton of $S[u]$ is correct, the answer is given again by second last paragraph of the blog post. Otherwise (i.e. when there should have been $0 \leq y < u(x)$ instead of $0 \leq y \leq u(x)$ in the definiton of $S[u]$), the answer is given below.

Maybe someone else sees this problem and can give a better clarification about it.

**Answer:** Approximating $u$ by an increasing sequence of simple functions $(f_j)$ means that

\begin{equation}
f_j(x) \leq u(x)
\end{equation}

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $j \in \mathbb{N}$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function) for the standard construction of the functions $f_j$). If we write for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{equation}
S[u]_x := \{x\} \times \{y \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \leq y \leq u(x) \} \subseteq S[u] 
\end{equation}

then it follows that

\begin{equation}
S[f_j]_x \subseteq S[u]_x 
\end{equation}

for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $j \in \mathbb{N}$. Because ($f_j$) converges pointwise to $u$, we have

\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{j = 0}^{\infty}S[f_j]_x = S[u]_x 
\end{equation}

and because

\begin{equation}
\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} S[u]_x = S[u], \,\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} S[f_j]_x = S[f_j]
\end{equation}

we get that

\begin{equation}
S[u] = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} S[u]_x = \bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \big(\bigcup_{j = 0}^{\infty}S[f_j]_x\big) = \bigcup_{j = 0}^{\infty} \big(\bigcup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} S[f_j]_x\big) = \bigcup_{j = 0}^{\infty}S[f_j] 
\end{equation}

So the equality holds indeed, and your conclusion is right.

Comment: Very helpful! Is it more correct to say that $S[u]=\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} S[f_j] \cup (\{x:u(x)=\infty\} \times \{\infty\})$ since these simple functions are always $\mathbb{R}$ valued? But then $(\{x:u(x)=\infty\} \times \{\infty\})$ is not in ${\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R^2})$ (or is it? If not, then is it true that the question really should of said $u:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty)$ (that is, $u$ is finite))?

Comment: @satokun: I don't think that this consideration is needed here. The underlying set of your measure space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, what means that there aren't any points $(x, \infty) \in S[u]$ (although $u$ can take the value infinity). If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a point such that $u(x) = \infty$, then (using my notation from the answer) $S[u]_x = \{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$, and because simple functions can converge pointwise to infinity (in $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{\bar R}$), we have $\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} S[f_j]_x = \{x\} \times \{y \in \mathbb{R} : 0 \leq y \leq \infty \} = S[u]_x$.

Comment: @satokun: Why did you unaccept the answer? Is there still something unclear?

Comment: Dear user331406, I believe that the union $S[u]=\bigcup_j S[f_j]$ is not equal. I have found this website https://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2010/07/20/upper-and-lower-ordinate-sets/
that I think is worth reading. I do, nevertheless, appreciate your time and effort given to answer this question!

Comment: @satokun: You are right, I have to apologize for my answer, it only works if we consider $(x,y) \in S[u]$ such that $0 \leq y < u(x)$. I should have thought more about your hint instead of just assuming it was right and building an answer up on that. However, do you know if we are considering $S[u] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ or $S[u] \subseteq \bar{\mathbb{R}} \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ ? If it's the first, then I think that the method with the $\{f \cap n \}$ in your reference could work with a little change when $u(x) = \infty$.

Comment: I think, due to the hint, that there may have been a misprint and $S[u]$ really should have been $S[u]=\{(x,y):0\le y < u(x)\}$. Otherwise, if it really was a "$\le$" between $y$ and $u(x)$ (i.e. $y\le u(x)$ in the definition of $S[u]$) then I don't know if $S[u]$ can be viewed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ anymore. Since the question was to ultimately show that $S[u]\in {\cal{B}}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ I believe there was a misprint. (So the hint provided is correct, as well as your answer!)

Comment: If not, then probably the function $u$ must have had been $u:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$ with the original definition of $S[u]$ correct, and thus having to follow the method in the website. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @satokun: You are probably right with the misprint. I would even say that the problem is not well-posed since they didn't state in the definiton of $S[u]$ wheter $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ or $(x,y) \in \bar{\mathbb{R}} \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}$ (I implicitly assumed that they mean the first, since the measure space is $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not $\bar{\mathbb{R}} \times \bar{\mathbb{R}}$). I really think that either the hint is wrong or that the definition of $S[u]$ is not correct.

Comment: @satokun: However, I think that $S[u]$ can be considered as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ even if the definiton of $u$ and $S[u]$ is correct, because if $u(x) < \infty$, then $(x,y) \in S[u] \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq y \leq u(x)$, and if $u(x) = \infty$, then $(x,y) \in S[u] \Leftrightarrow 0 \leq y < \infty$ since $y = \infty$ is not possible in $\mathbb{R}^2$. But my answer is still not correct in this case because we have troubles when $u(x) < \infty$. I will make an edit to my answer to include what we have discussed here.